Symmetry-protected topological (SPT) order, invertible topological order, and intrinsic topological order
I am a bit confused about these three concepts... In my opinion, SPT phases are gapped phases protected by certain symmetries and short-range entangled, such as topological insulator; invertible topological order phases are also short-range entangled in the absence of symmetry, such as Chern insulator; intrinsic topological order phases are long-range entangled with fractional excitations, such as fractional quantum hall states. So they are three distinct types of topological order. I want to know what's wrong with my understanding, any answers would be appreciated.

What you wrote seems perfectly correct, what’s the confusion?
